# Cassandra Saving JSON data in Text Column

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

In Cassandra DB I have column name as `custom_extensions` which can contain `List<AppEncoded>` where AppEncoded is an `UDT`. The `UDT` has following fields

```
  type -> TEXT
  code -> TEXT
  value - TEXT
```

While saving data to DB the `value` field can expect input as object.

```
  CurrencyTO:
  field -> amount
  field -> Symbol
  field -> formattedAmount
```

The implementation to save the column value in DB is as follows:

```
   JacksonJsonCodec<CurrencyTO> jacksonJsonCodec = new JacksonJsonCodec<>(CurrencyTO.class);
   appEncodedValue.setValue(jacksonJsonCodec.format(CurrencyTO.getValue()));
```

CurrencyTo is extending TranserObject which has following attributes as well.
If I see in DB I am seeing the following results:

```
 "value": "'{\"serviceResult\":{\"messagesResult\":[]},\"attributeNames\":[\"amount\",\"isoCode\",\"symbol\",\"decimalValue\",\"formattedAmount\"],\"metadata\":null,\"this\":null,\"amount\":\"45\",\"isoCode\":\"USD\",\"symbol\":\"$\",\"decimalValue\":2.0,\"formattedAmount\":null}'"
```

The result added the `serviceResult`, `messageResult`, `metadata` and some `\` characters as well.

The Expected Result Should be similar as following in DB

```
"value": {
  "amount": 90,
  "Symbol": "$",
  "formattedAmount" : "90.00"
}
```

The Reference I followed for implementation is:
[custom_codecs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.1/manual/custom_codecs/)

Comment: How do you check it in DB? what tool are you using?

Comment: I am using DataStax Studio Version 2.0.0